# C++ error when using std::vector on mingw and powershell

Tags: c++, powershell, git-bash

I have come across some strage behaviour when executing a simple program that uses `std::vector` with `powershell`

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  auto v = std::vector<int>{};
  v.push_back(0);  

  std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";

  return 0;
}
```

`g++ -v` returns `gcc version 11.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)`

I then compile the program with `g++ main.cpp -o main.exe` and i get an output executable.

When I run `.\main.exe` with `powershell` I get no console output but when i run the same executable with `git bash` I get `Hello, World!` printed to the console.

Ive tested both `Powershell 7` and `Windows PowerShell`.

When I remove the both lines that have to do wiht `std::vector` it works in both shells.

When I run the executbale from 'cmd' I get the following error message
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happended to me because I had **MULTIPLE** instances of gcc installed in my windows system and had both of them in `PATH`.
This confused the dynamic loader.
Deleting one, so that **ONLY ON** instance of gcc is available in `PATH`